# Flask admin inline model instance from form

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I havewritten my custom `inline-model` widget by overriding `RenderTemplateWidget, InlineModelFormList, InlineModelConverter`, but I would like to have access to `inline-model` instance from widget template. Is there any possibility to pass it through those classes or is it already accessible from template?
Here are my classes:

```
class CustomInlineFieldListWidget(RenderTemplateWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomInlineFieldListWidget, self).__init__('custom/field_list.html')


class CustomnInlineModelFormList(InlineModelFormList):
    widget = CustomInlineFieldListWidget()

    def display_row_controls(self, field):
        return False


class CustomInlineModelConverter(InlineModelConverter):
    inline_field_list_type = CustomInlineModelFormList
```

So far it is only overriding path to the template, but i can't access for model instance for specific inline model in html